# Visual Studio gives a NullReferenceException when trying to add my control!

Tags: c#, user-controls

Here's the error:
[image]

It says the source of the exception is on Line20 of my class. Here is my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WebServiceScanner
{
    public partial class imageList : UserControl
    {
        private int XPosition = 0;

        public imageList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Images.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Images_CollectionChanged);
        }       

        public ObservableCollection<selectablePicture> Images { get; set; }

        public void AddImage(selectablePicture image)
        {
            Images.Add(image);
        }

        public void RemoveImage(selectablePicture image)
        {
            Images.Remove(image);
        }

        public void MoveImageLeft(int index)
        {
            selectablePicture tmpImage = Images[index];
            Images[index] = Images[index - 1];
            Images[index - 1] = tmpImage;
        }

        public void MoveImageRight(int index)
        {
            selectablePicture tmpImage = Images[index];
            Images[index] = Images[index + 1];
            Images[index + 1] = tmpImage;
        }

        void Images_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RedrawImages();
        }

        private void RedrawImages()
        {
            foreach (var picture in Images)
            {
                picture.Location = new Point(XPosition + panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, 0);
                XPosition += 130;
                panel1.Controls.Add(picture);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm doing something dumb like setting an event handler at the constructor. Any ideas? This user control isn't really that complex, so there are few places where something could be wrong.

If you guys need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a statement to instantiate `Images`.

```
public imageList()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Images = new ObservableCollection<selectablePicture>();
    Images.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Images_CollectionChanged);
}
```

Comment: Adding that to my constructor, now gives me this error:http://min.us/iGxFy.JPG I'm stumped. what could be causing this.

Comment: This message indicates that the `selectablePicture` class needs to be marked `Serializable` so that the object can be serialized for webservice communication.  Also, thanks for posting screenshots.  Those are very helpful!

Comment: @Phil: Why would that need to come into the picture? Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: @Serg - The need for serializable objects came into play when you needed to expose the types via webservices.  Only objects that can be serialized (converted to some commonly agreed upon format) can be publicly involved in webservice calls.

Comment: Using `Serializable` will require you to have a public parameterless constructor unless you implement `ISerializable`, IIRM...

Comment: @Phil, my question is why this is even mentioned by visual studio; i'm not using web services at all :P any suggestions?

Comment: @Serg - Ah, I had assumed that the name `WebServiceScanner` indicated that you were leveraging web services in some way.  It turns out that the reason that you need a parameterless constructor is that the designer needs to be able to instantiate the object, and it obviously has no parameters that it could pass to a constructor.  Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it is something to do with the fact that Images isn't set to any value so the control is trying to render it for DesignView but Images is null hence the NullReferenceException. It's probably the code in the Constructor when it tries to register against the Images which will probably run before any injection code setting images.

Answer (score 0):

Does `< selectablePicture >` have a parameterless public constructor? And are you instancing `Images`?

Comment: No, I don't have a parameterless constructor. Why do I need one?

Comment: I had received an error on a type in which I didn't have a parameterless public constructor. Wasn't really sure if this would be the cause for the exception - just thought I would offer it as a possibility.